# my while loop gets called instead of my function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So When I  try to call my customer_name() function is keeps calling my while loops first. it always seems to call my phone_number while loop then goes onto the customer_name loop. then if I take the phone_number while loop away it calls the while loop for pizza_menu. I've tried to fix this several times but with no luck, could someone help me? Also I tried to add all my variables customer_name, phone_number etc to print out at the end but it keeps giving me "not defined" I wanted to add them all into a list then print hem out at the end. I wish someone can help me and I really appreciate that. I am not allowed to have classes and such because we haven't learned that yet.
Using python 3.3

```
premium_pizzas = ["Supreme Cheese", "The Legendary pizza", "Pentakill supreme", "Teeto shroomo supreme", "The volcanic rengar", "Cheese and Ham" , "Vegetriano" ]
gourmet_pizzas = ["Flame Gorilla", "Snazzy chicken", "Intergalactic BBQ", "BBQ Chicken", "Hellfire"]

num_pizzas = -1


def customer_name():
    customer_name =""
    while customer_name  == "":
          try:
            customer_name = str(input("Please enter your name"))
          except:
            print("error you must enter something! (cannot be a number)")

          else:
            user_info()


def delivery_details():
    delivery_address = ""
    while delivery_address =="":
        try:
            delivery_address = str(input("please enter your delivery address"))
        except:
            print("error you must enter something!")

phone_number = 0
while (phone_number <0) or (phone_number <7):
        try:
            phone_number = int(input("Please enter your phone number:\n\t"))
        except:
            print("Phone number must be integer only(No only.)")

        else:
            pizza_list()





def pizza_list():
 num_pizzas = -1
while( num_pizzas <= 0 ) or ( num_pizzas > 5 ):
    try:
        num_pizzas = int( input( 'How many pizzas would you like (max of 5):'))
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')

pizza_dict = {"premium_pizza_price":8.50, "gourmet_pizza_price":5.00, "selected_pizzas":0, "num_premium_pizzas":0, "num_gourmet_pizzas":0}
print('\n==Premium Pizzas==\n')
for i in range (0,len(premium_pizzas)):
    print (str(i+1) + '. ' + premium_pizzas[i])
print('\n==Gourmet Pizzas==\n')
for i in range (0,len(gourmet_pizzas)):
    print (str(i+1) + '. ' + gourmet_pizzas[i])

print('\nEnter "next" to move on.\n')

while(True):
    if( num_pizzas == 0 ):
        break;
    try:
        selected = input('Select Your Premium Pizza: ')
        if(selected == 'next'):
            break;
        else:
            selected = int(selected)
        if(selected<=0) or (selected > len(premium_pizzas)):
            print('Invalid Input')
        else:
            pizza_dict['num_premium_pizzas']+=1
            num_pizzas -=1
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')

    print(' ')

while(True):
    if( num_pizzas == 0 ):
        break;
    try:
        selected = input('Select Your Gourmet Pizza: ')
        if(selected == 'next'):
            break;
        else:
            selected = int(selected)
        if(selected<=0) or (selected > len(gourmet_pizzas)):
            print('Invalid Input')
        else:
            pizza_dict['num_gourmet_pizzas']+=1
            num_pizzas -=1
    except:
        print('Invalid Input')




def user_info():
    get_user_info = ""
    while not get_user_info == "1":
     get_user_info =str(input("Press 1 for delivery press\nPress 2 for pickup\n\t:"))
    if get_user_info == "1":
        delivery_details()

    elif get_user_info == "2":
        pizza_list()


receipt = [customer_name]
#print('\nTotal number of premium pizzas: ' + str(pizza_dict['num_premium_pizzas']));
#print('Total number of gourmet pizzas: ' + str(pizza_dict['num_gourmet_pizzas']));
#cost = (pizza_dict["num_premium_pizzas"]*pizza_dict['premium_pizza_price'])+(pizza_dict["num_gourmet_pizzas"]*pizza_dict['gourmet_pizza_price']*3.00);
#print('\nTotal cost: ' + str(cost))





customer_name()
#delivery_details()
#geprint('\nTotal number of premium pizzas: ' + str(pizza_dict['num_premium_pizzas']));
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong - for example, the `while` loop for the phone number is *outside* the `delivery_details` function. Whitespace matters in Python!

Comment: oh my lord! I will see if this is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your inconsistent indentation, your phone number loop is outside of a function and therefore gets run as soon as the script is.